# Do I need to create/update both models to insert a one-to-many in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm trying to insert a one-to-many relationship. An example taken from [flask-sqlalchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html):

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person',
                                lazy='dynamic')

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

I've written view that allows an authenticated user to create a new address. I'm using flask-login to get the authenticated `current_user`. I came up with (not tested):

```
import flask.ext.login import login_required, current_user

@app.route('/new_address', methods = ["GET","POST"])
@login_required
def new_address():
    address_form = AddressForm()
    if address_form.validate_on_submit():
        address = Address(email='foo@bar.com', person_id=current_user.id)
        user = Person.query.get(current_user.id)
        user.addresses.append(address)
        db.session.add(address)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(...)
    return render_template(...)
```

Two things confuse me.

The first: For one-to-many relationships, do I need to update both models? ie, appending the new address to the Person model AND setting the person_id on the Address model?

The second: If yes to above, is there a way to append the new address onto  the Person model directly through `current_user` or do I have to query for the Person model using `current_user.id`, and then updating that model like I have done?
ie,

Instead of:

```
user = Person.query.get(current_user.id)
user.addresses.append(address)
db.session.commit()
```

Can it be:

```
 current_user.addresses.append(address)
 db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to actively append the address to a Person model, this is embedded in the one-to-many relationship as part of your tables setup and handled by the database.

The code below should be enough (copying from your code, minus redundant operations):

```
address = Address(email='foo@bar.com', person_id=current_user.id)
db.session.add(address)
db.session.commit()
```

You can easily verify you're adding addresses by actually adding a few and running:

`print (db.session.query(Address).filter_by(person_id=current_user.id).count())`

Note: if this is done outside of a logged-in user context within flask, simply replace `current_user.id` with a relevant Person id number.

You'll see there are as many addresses associated with the user as you committed to the database.

Comment: Okay, I see. For the second question, let's say I already have an address that I fetched from the DB, and I want to append it to the authenticated user. Is there a way to update that authenticated user in the DB by directly updating `current_user`, or I do have to do what I have done (get Person model from `current_user.id`... etc).

Comment: How did you fetch the address? Is it attached to a Person id? if not, how was it created?